# how to reset inMemoryDatabase and its primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I use a inMemoryDatabase in my asp.net core web api, 
it is defined like that:
in the startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<TempContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("ImageDataBase"));
```

in the context:

```
public class TempContext : DbContext
{
  public TempContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
  { }

  public DbSet<Images> Images { get; set; }
```

the images class:

```
public class PathImages
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string RawImage { get; set; }
  public string ProcessedImage { get; set; }
}
```

and I would like to reset it depending on what the user do on the client side.
so I tried in the controller of the view:

```
_context.Images.RemoveRange(_context.Images.ToArray());
await _context2.SaveChangesAsync();
```

but the primary key is not reseted and my view needs it to be reseted.

then I tried:

```
await _context.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
```

and

```
await _context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
```

but it doesn't reset the primary key either.

is there a way to reset the inmemorydatabase, including its primary key ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently. It has been fixed in the EF Core 3.0 Preview 4, though. The [EF Core 3.0 Preview 4 announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-3-0-preview-4/) and the associated [Github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6872).

Comment: ok thanks, I'll take the primary key of the first element to subtract then I guess, using `_context.Images.FirstAsync();` probably